# Why is nothing being written to file?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

The file is being created, but nothing is there when i open it.

```
StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(
    "C:\\Users\\cinim\\Unity Projects\\QC\\TestPics\\failedItems.csv");

foreach(string s in failedItems)
{
    Debug.Log("writing " + s);
    stream.WriteLine(s);
}
```

no errors just empty file, should be a list of 1 - 10 items

Comment: You need to close the file - `stream.Close()`

Comment: Files need closure.

Comment: Close the file, you must.

Comment: `using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("....failedItems.csv")) { .... 
}`

Comment: Or `stream.Flush()`

Comment: Thank you! Just had to close it!

Comment: No, you should use WriteAllLines()

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  It has a clear problem statement and code that reproduces the problem.  The problem may be a simple one, but that is not a reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `System.IO.File` class instead of the `StreamWriter` class. The `File` class has some very handy static methods that wrap `StreamWriter` calls, for example:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\cinim\Unity Projects\QC\TestPics\failedItems.csv",
    failedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the program terminating before the stream is closed.

You should be able to achieve this by making sure it is closed and disposed.

Example:

```cs
using (var stream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\cinim\Unity Projects\QC\TestPics\failedItems.csv"))
{
  foreach(string s in failedItems)
  {
    Debug.Log("writing " + s);
    stream.WriteLine(s);
  }
  stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: No need to explicitly call `Close` here - `using` will take care of that when the block ends.

Comment: @RufusL, that's true... doesn't hurt.